# Build tool for a complex C++/Python project

Tags: python, c++, docker, build, build-tools

## Context

I'm working on a project composed of multiple C++ and Python projects. A typical component is for instance composed of:

- Pure C++ library (depending on other native libraries)
- C/C++ Python binding (depending on the native libraries)
- Pure Python glue code (depending on other Python libraries and Python bindings)

A component can depend of another components.

## Current state

C++ components are build using CMake and produced RPM files. Python components are packaged using setuptool to Python wheels. Final application is packaged in a Docker image.

As you can guess, this heterogeneous environment is very difficult to maintain:

- Dependency management is very difficult and error prone. C++ dependencies are managed using the RPM features. Python dependencies using setuptool.
- Build result deployment is hard. 2 servers are maintained, 1 for RPM repository and 1 for a Pypi repository
- Installation is difficult: Integrity between RPM and Python components are not guaranteed. Fetch and install the application is hard as there is no unified dependency management
- Version tagging in control version system is also difficult: you have to change the version in the Python and C++ project. We really need a single entry point.

I'm sure some people out there have already encountered this kind of problem and I'm looking for a good and durable technical solution. We already tried to managed these projects using Maven (proof of concept) but our experience of this build system is not really positive: it lacks of flexibility and we've not found how to manage custom artifact (RPM, wheels) and the final installation.

Do you have any ideas on how design a maintainable build system in this context?

Comment: This may be too broad or too opinion based a question, I don't know. Personally I would want to have one install system (RPM) and I would probably keep the individual projects' internal build systems and have an overarching `Makefile` to manage the cross project relationships because make is very flexible, powerful and portable.

Comment: concerning the last bullet : I found actually better to have two repositories; but , since it is what you ask, what prevent you to have a unique one ?

Comment: I hope that when you said control version system, you do not refer to cvs but you actually use a more modern one . If not jump to svn or git immediatly !

Comment: Last but not least : I have worked  in a situation opposite to you, full of components depending of each others, built in one BIG (enormous) solution. The result is broken build every single 5 minutes and really hard to test in isolation.

Comment: Finally, I would say that the key point is that each component must be managed / tested independantly, each one providing API and ABI stability ! Change required on interface must go first through a deprecation phase (6months or more) which gives time for other components to be updated.